# Justifying Text in Word 2007

Tags: microsoft-word, alignment

How can you justify text in Word 2007 and not have the last sentence look really spaced out? IE:

```
The  Last     Line        Looks      Like    This   to     fill   the    space.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normal justification of a paragraph does not make the last line spaced out; instead, it is normally flushed left with no extra spacing between words. The problem you describe seems to appear only when the paragraph has been terminated by a forced line break (Shift Enter) rather than normal paragraph terminator (Enter).

So clicking on the end of the last line, hitting the rubout key “←” (to remove the forced line break) and hitting Enter should fix the situation.

Answer (score 0):

Please correct me if my answer does not describe your problem perfectly, but a few minutes ago, I experienced the following:

```
The  Last     Line        Looks      Like    This   to     fill   the    space.
```

URL

Then to solve the problem, I  only placed my cursor at the left of 'URL' and clicked 'Enter'.