# Microsoft word - how to remove weird spaces

Tags: macos, mac, microsoft-word, microsoft-office

Suddenly in some lines in my document, the space between the words is longer than usual

look

[image]

the space between the red boxes is more than the normal, and that for example just happend in two lines, then it become normal

this is my word version

[image]

what's up guys ?!

Comment: Did you used the [justify alignment](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Align-or-justify-text-B9096ED4-7323-4FF3-921A-1BA7BA31FAF1)? Try switching the left alignment.

Comment: [Align or justify text](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Align-or-justify-text-b9096ed4-7323-4ff3-921a-1ba7ba31faf1)

Comment: @Nimesh the whole document has the same alilgmne,t which is Justify Text, so why these two lines specially have this extra big space ?

Comment: @DavidPostill i am using Justify Text, but it is working fine in all document (100 page) except these two lines

Comment: @sarah See [Justifying Text in Word 2007](http://superuser.com/a/414612). Remove any <shift>+<enter> (forced line breaks)

Comment: @sarah open *Format/Paragraph* check if you have selected don't hyphenate, spacing like this happens when you have decided to have whole words on the line, it might be configured also in your styles, and decide on each style the kind of format that you need for an specific paragraph. HTH

Answer (score 1):

It could be that Word doesn't know how to hyphenate the long words you redacted in that screenshot (I'm guessing they're foreign-language words or some kind of linguistic jargon?), so it can't break/wrap the lines well, which throws off the justification.

Consider manually adding "optional hyphens" in all the appropriate places (e.g. between each of the syllables) in those words to allow the lines to break properly. Optional hyphens don't show unless they're needed for line-breaking a word. To enter an optional hyphen, hit <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> (Command-hyphen) in Word for Mac, or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> (Control-hyphen) in Word for Windows.

Once you've properly inserted optional hyphens into the words in the two lines you cited, you might want to search/replace all instances of those words so all instances have all the hyphenation hints, so this doesn't happen again in other places as your text reflows as you edit your document.