# Space within text - Word

Tags: microsoft-word-2010

In my thesis' references there are huge spaces between text. I assume due to justify alignment. Unfortunately justify alignment is a rule to use it. So what can I do to remove those spaces? I have Word 2010. Here is the link to an image:

[image: http://imgur.com/a/pNS2X]

Comment: Is it the last line of each reference?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Justifying Text in Word 2007](http://superuser.com/questions/414610/justifying-text-in-word-2007)

Comment: No, it looks like this: Aegean      Vacations.      (2016).       Retrieved      on             8.           4.             2016           from         http://blabla.com. Hope this helps as I can't post an image.

Comment: Hmm. Can you add a screenshot (with paragraph symbol display enabled)? StackExchange uses Imgur for image storage. Upload your image(s) to [Imgur](http://www.imgur.com) and you will get link(s) you can share. [Edit] your question to include the link(s) and someone with sufficient reputation will inline the image(s) for you.

Comment: Hope I did it :)

Comment: Yes you did it ;) Looks like the problem is a combination of justified text together with more text than will fit on one line :/ I'm not sure how to get around that. There are some hints in [Justify Paragraphs for a Clean Finish but Avoid Wide Gaps in Text](http://suiteminute.com/justify-paragraphs-for-a-clean-finish-but-avoid-wide-gaps-in-text/) - "Fixing a Short Sentence" looks like it might work. Unfortunately I don't have Word to test it with.

Comment: It helps just a little bit, but the spaces are still there.

Comment: Try using Alt+0160 (Fixed width, non-breaking space) instead of a normal space in the problem line. See [Non-breaking space bug](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_windows8/non-breaking-space-bug/6556aa2d-b10f-445d-8b66-fccde772c6e4?page=1) for more info. They also suggest using "If you want a set space, use a typographical space such as en space.  The 1/4 en space is roughly  equivalent to a word space;  the em space is the width of the font size and, so, much wider than a word space. All are available from the  Symbols > Special Characters tab"

Comment: Is this something you typed or something you copied and pasted from a web page?  If the latter, what you copied may not have been simple text, there could be layout controls that are giving Word indigestion.  Try deleting the pasted chunk, including any associated paragraph mark, and then manually typing the words.

Answer (score 0):

For word 2010:

- Click the File tab, Options, Advanced.
- Go to absolute bottom of the Advanced options, and click to expand Layout Options.
- Tick “Do full justification like WordPerfect...” (this Options list is in alphabetical order).

Source:
http://suiteminute.com/justify-paragraphs-for-a-clean-finish-but-avoid-wide-gaps-in-text/